# sql server can't start error code 1814

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

My pc can't start sqlserver 2008 R2.
this is my sql server errorlog

```
2018-05-02 16:32:47.26 Server      Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (RTM) - 10.50.1600.1 (X64) 
    Apr  2 2010 15:48:46 
    Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation
    Enterprise Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.1 <X64> (Build 7601: Service Pack 1)

2018-05-02 16:32:47.26 Server      (c) Microsoft Corporation.
2018-05-02 16:32:47.26 Server      All rights reserved.
2018-05-02 16:32:47.26 Server      Server process ID is 4856.
2018-05-02 16:32:47.26 Server      System Manufacturer: 'OEM', System Model: 'OEM'.
2018-05-02 16:32:47.26 Server      Authentication mode is MIXED.
2018-05-02 16:32:47.26 Server      Logging SQL Server messages in file 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Log\ERRORLOG'.
2018-05-02 16:32:47.27 Server      This instance of SQL Server last reported using a process ID of 4388 at 5/2/2018 4:32:14 PM (local) 5/2/2018 10:47:14 AM (UTC). This is an informational message only; no user action is required.
2018-05-02 16:32:47.27 Server      Registry startup parameters: 
     -d C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\master.mdf
     -e C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Log\ERRORLOG
     -l C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\mastlog.ldf
2018-05-02 16:32:47.29 Server      SQL Server is starting at normal priority base (=7). This is an informational message only. No user action is required.
2018-05-02 16:32:47.29 Server      Detected 2 CPUs. This is an informational message; no user action is required.
2018-05-02 16:32:47.30 Server      Using locked pages for buffer pool.
2018-05-02 16:32:47.32 Server      Using dynamic lock allocation.  Initial allocation of 2500 Lock blocks and 5000 Lock Owner blocks per node.  This is an informational message only.  No user action is required.
2018-05-02 16:32:47.35 Server      Node configuration: node 0: CPU mask: 0x0000000000000003:0 Active CPU mask: 0x0000000000000003:0. This message provides a description of the NUMA configuration for this computer. This is an informational message only. No user action is required.
2018-05-02 16:32:47.38 spid7s      Starting up database 'master'.
2018-05-02 16:32:47.52 spid7s      Resource governor reconfiguration succeeded.
2018-05-02 16:32:47.52 spid7s      SQL Server Audit is starting the audits. This is an informational message. No user action is required.
2018-05-02 16:32:47.52 spid7s      SQL Server Audit has started the audits. This is an informational message. No user action is required.
2018-05-02 16:32:47.57 spid7s      FILESTREAM: effective level = 0, configured level = 0, file system access share name = 'MSSQLSERVER'.
2018-05-02 16:32:47.58 spid7s      SQL Trace ID 1 was started by login "sa".
2018-05-02 16:32:47.58 spid7s      Starting up database 'mssqlsystemresource'.
2018-05-02 16:32:47.64 spid7s      The resource database build version is 10.50.1600. This is an informational message only. No user action is required.
2018-05-02 16:32:47.79 spid7s      Server name is 'JUNG-PC'. This is an informational message only. No user action is required.
2018-05-02 16:32:47.79 spid10s     Starting up database 'model'.
2018-05-02 16:32:47.80 spid10s     Error: 17204, Severity: 16, State: 1.
2018-05-02 16:32:47.80 spid10s     FCB::Open failed: Could not open file e:\sql10_main_t.obj.x86fre\sql\mkmastr\databases\objfre\i386\model.mdf for file number 1.  OS error: 3(The system cannot find the path specified.).
2018-05-02 16:32:47.80 spid10s     Error: 5120, Severity: 16, State: 101.
2018-05-02 16:32:47.80 spid10s     Unable to open the physical file "e:\sql10_main_t.obj.x86fre\sql\mkmastr\databases\objfre\i386\model.mdf". Operating system error 3: "3(The system cannot find the path specified.)".
2018-05-02 16:32:47.80 spid10s     Error: 17207, Severity: 16, State: 1.
2018-05-02 16:32:47.80 spid10s     FileMgr::StartLogFiles: Operating system error 2(The system cannot find the file specified.) occurred while creating or opening file 'e:\sql10_main_t.obj.x86fre\sql\mkmastr\databases\objfre\i386\modellog.ldf'. Diagnose and correct the operating system error, and retry the operation.
2018-05-02 16:32:47.80 spid10s     File activation failure. The physical file name "e:\sql10_main_t.obj.x86fre\sql\mkmastr\databases\objfre\i386\modellog.ldf" may be incorrect.
2018-05-02 16:32:47.80 spid10s     Error: 945, Severity: 14, State: 2.
2018-05-02 16:32:47.80 spid10s     Database 'model' cannot be opened due to inaccessible files or insufficient memory or disk space.  See the SQL Server errorlog for details.
2018-05-02 16:32:47.80 spid10s     Could not create tempdb. You may not have enough disk space available. Free additional disk space by deleting other files on the tempdb drive and then restart SQL Server. Check for additional errors in the event log that may indicate why the tempdb files could not be initialized.
2018-05-02 16:32:47.80 spid10s     SQL Trace was stopped due to server shutdown. Trace ID = '1'. This is an informational message only; no user action is required.
```

Can anyone help to resolve this problem.

Answer (score 2):

```
2018-05-02 16:32:47.80 spid10s     FCB::Open failed: Could not open file e:\sql10_main_t.obj.x86fre\sql\mkmastr\databases\objfre\i386\model.mdf for file number 1.  OS error: 3(The system cannot find the path specified.).
2018-05-02 16:32:47.80 spid10s     Error: 5120, Severity: 16, State: 101.
2018-05-02 16:32:47.80 spid10s     Unable to open the physical file "e:\sql10_main_t.obj.x86fre\sql\mkmastr\databases\objfre\i386\model.mdf". Operating system error 3: "3(The system cannot find the path specified.)".
2018-05-02 16:32:47.80 spid10s     Error: 17207, Severity: 16, State: 1.
2018-05-02 16:32:47.80 spid10s     FileMgr::StartLogFiles: Operating system error 2(The system cannot find the file specified.) occurred while creating or opening file 'e:\sql10_main_t.obj.x86fre\sql\mkmastr\databases\objfre\i386\modellog.ldf'. Diagnose and correct the operating system error, and retry the operation.
2018-05-02 16:32:47.80 spid10s     File activation failure. The physical file name "e:\sql10_main_t.obj.x86fre\sql\mkmastr\databases\objfre\i386\modellog.ldf" may be incorrect.
2018-05-02 16:32:47.80 spid10s     Error: 945, Severity: 14, State: 2.
2018-05-02 16:32:47.80 spid10s     Database 'model' cannot be opened due to inaccessible files or insufficient memory or disk space.  See the SQL Server errorlog for details.
2018-05-02 16:32:47.80 spid10s     Could not create tempdb. You may not have enough disk space available. Free additional disk space by deleting other files on the tempdb drive and then restart SQL Server. Check for additional errors in the event log that may indicate why the tempdb files could not be initialized.
2018-05-02 16:32:47.80 spid10s     SQL Trace was stopped due to server shutdown. Trace ID = '1'. This is an informational message only; no user action is required.
```

The errors are self-explanatory.

```
"The system cannot find the path specified" 

Database 'model' cannot be opened due to inaccessible files or insufficient memory
```

Make sure location/files exist in your E:\ drive and you have enough free disk space or memory (RAM) available in your system.